# How to control GPU memory size with tf.estimator

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to control the size of GPU memory allocated for one tensorflow estimator tf.estimator.Estimator. The purpose is to only allocate half to run other tensorflow net on the same GPU. I found for the contrib version but not for the official. Someone knows if it's possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create an `Estimator` instance, you can pass in the constructor's `config` a [`tf.estimator.RunConfig`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig) instance.
The `RunConfig` has a `session_config` attribute you can use to set a `tf.ConfigProto` with the session's parameters.

In code, this translates to:

```python
session_config = tf.ConfigProto()
session_config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5
estimator_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(session_config=session_config)
my_estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(..., config=estimator_config)
```